# In R, can I use data table to update values in a data frame with column names containing a white space?

Tags: r, datatable

I'm trying to update several values in my columns using `data table`, however I have to use the method of having to rename the column names to ones without a white space, as below. Is this possible to do without having to rename my column names to remove the whitespace?

```
In <- In %>%
  rename(
    duty_av='AV Duty Rate',
    duty_spec='Specific Duty Rate',
    duty_nature='Duty Nature'
  )

setDT(In)
setDT(trqs)
In[trqs, on=c("TL","TLS"),duty_av:=i.duty_av]
In[trqs, on=c("TL","TLS"),duty_spec:=i.duty_spec]
In[trqs, on=c("TL","TLS"),duty_nature:=i.duty_nature]

In <- In %>%
  rename(
    'AV Duty Rate'=duty_av,
    'Specific Duty Rate'=duty_spec,
    'Duty Nature'=duty_nature
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to update the values in your columns without having to rename the column names to remove the whitespace. One way to achieve this is by using backticks (`) around the column names with whitespace when referring to them in your code. This allows you to preserve the original column names while performing the desired updates

Try out this:

```
library(data.table)



setDT(In)
setDT(trqs)

# Update values 
In[trqs, on = c("TL", "TLS"), `AV Duty Rate` := i.`AV Duty Rate`]
In[trqs, on = c("TL", "TLS"), `Specific Duty Rate` := i.`Specific Duty Rate`]
In[trqs, on = c("TL", "TLS"), `Duty Nature` := i.`Duty Nature`]
```

Comment: Hi when I do that red lines under := i.`AV Duty Rate` and it doesn't run